# Implemented JpaRepository in SpringService returning NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

So I have this Model/Repository/Service setup where I'm trying to save an object. Everything works fine up until when I try and save the document. Whenever I try to save it, I get this stacktrace...

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at **.pricing.account.service.impl.BcpDocumentServiceImpl.save(BcpDocumentServiceImpl.java:62)
    at **.pricing.tool.impl.SowServiceImpl.createBACPSOW(SowServiceImpl.java:81)
    at **.pricing.account.web.BCPController.bcpSubmit(BCPController.java:69)
```

I defined the repositories in my config.xml file...

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.spohnconsulting.pricing.account.repository"/>
```

Here's the code for the /Repository/Service itself

The Repository:

```
package com.spohnconsulting.pricing.account.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface BcpDocumentRepository extends JpaRepository<BcpDocument, Long> {


}
```

Interface for the Service:

```
/**
 *
 * @author willkara
 */
public interface BcpDocumentService {

    void save(BCP bcp,String dest);

}
```

The service itself:

```
@Service
public class BcpDocumentServiceImpl implements BcpDocumentService {

    @Autowired
    private BcpDocumentRepository bcpDocumentRepository;

    @Override
    public void save(BCP bcp, String dest) {
        BcpDocument bcpDoc = new BcpDocument();
        bcpDoc.setDocumentCreationDate(new Date().toString());
        bcpDoc.setDocumentName("TESTING");

        try {
            bcpDoc.setDocumentData(Files.readAllBytes(new File(dest).toPath()));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BcpDocumentServiceImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        bcpDocumentRepository.save(bcpDoc);

    }

}
```

But every-time I run it, I still get a NullPointerException. My guess is that somehow it's not being initialized correctly through Spring. My only concern is that I'm doing the same kind of implementation for the login mechanism (users/roles)

Comment: How do you create `BcpDocumentServiceImpl`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I just Autowired it. I had to step out real quick so I'm not next to my computer

Comment: What is on line 62 in `BcpDocumentServiceImpl`?